# genfromtxt - Force column name generation for unknown number of columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have trouble getting numpy to load tabular data and automatically generate column names. It seems pretty simple but I cannot nail it.

If i knew the number of columns I could easily create `names` parameter, but I don't have this knowledge, and I would like to avoid prior introspection of the data file.

How can I force numpy to generate the column names, or use `tuple`-like `dtype` automatically, when I have no knowledge how many columns there are in file? I want to manipulate the column names after reading the data.

My approaches so far:

`data = np.genfromtxt(tar_member, unpack = True, names = '')` - I wanted to force automatic generation of column names by giving some "empty" parameter. Results with error `ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.`

`data = np.genfromtxt(tar_member, unpack = True, names = True)` - "Works" but consumes 1st row of data.

`data = np.genfromtxt(tar_member, unpack = True, dtype = None)` - Worked for data with mixed types. Automatic type guessing expanded `dtype` into a tuple, and assigned the names. However, for data where everything was actually `float`, `dtype` was set to `float64`, and I got `ValueError: there are no fields defined` when I tried accessing `data.dtype.names`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know there is a cleaner way to do this, but if you don't mind forcing the issue you can generate your dtype structure and assign it directly to the data array.

```
x = numpy.random.rand(10,10)
numpy.savetxt('test.out', x, delimiter=',')
dataa = numpy.genfromtxt('test.out',delimiter=",", dtype=None)
if dataa.dtype.names is None:#then dataa is homogenous?
  l1 = map(lambda z:('f%d'%(z),dataa.dtype),range(0,dataa.shape[1]))
  dataa.dtype = dtype(l1)

dataa.dtype
dataa.dtype.names
```

Comment: My current workaround is `if( len(data.dtype) == 0 ): new_dtype = list(zip(names, [data.dtype] * len(columns_meta) )) data.dtype = new_dtype`. So essentially the same idea. I wonder if there is a native nicer way, like with `names = True` but with out consuming 1st row, or `dtype=None` but with enforcing the expansion into `tuple`.

Comment: Gotcha, thought you were aware of such a trick.  Yeah, I don't know if there is a better way.  You'd think it would be possible to not consume the first row.

Comment: I figured it out and tried it about 2h after posting a question because I needed to make progress with rest of code that depends on it. So the 1st dirty solution passed. If there is no better way this gets accepted, at least it works.