# Trouble accessing column data by name

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have trouble getting a data from a structured `numpy` array via the column name. At the end is my relevant code. I think it's simple and short enough to be posted in whole (it's a sscce acutally).

There is a simple generation of data into a `test.out` file if it doesn't exists. I always load data from file, just for testing purposes. It is not important here (I think). Then I enforce using a structured array if the data in file was homogenous. I would like to access data via a column name like `data['f3']`, but I get it in kind of weird shape. I get a list of one-element lists. E.g:

```
shape: (10, 1), data['f3']:
[[ 0.50308252]
 [ 0.16259077]
 [ 0.5448315 ]
 [ 0.77284975]
 [ 0.01443514]
 [ 0.40232731]
 [ 0.6703865 ]
 [ 0.3918904 ]
 [ 0.07649033]
 [ 0.70849585]]
```

The desired output would be:

```
shape: (10, 1), data['f3']:
[ 0.50308252  0.16259077  0.5448315   0.77284975  0.01443514  0.40232731
  0.6703865   0.3918904   0.07649033  0.70849585]
```

Interestingly enough all reported shapes are the same (for the `data.shape` too).

Am I enforcing `dtype` in wrong way? I am pretty sure it can be done be cause [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7038659/1133179) shows same semantics with a desired result. I figured out a workaround with a `reshape` but it seems bizarre if it was necessary. This also works with lists of columns. You can set `col_name = ['f1', 'f3']` in my code. Is there a way to get it done with a simple `data[col_name]`?

The code:

```
import numpy
import os

def get_data():
  if not os.path.exists('test.out'):
    new_data = numpy.random.rand(10,10)
    numpy.savetxt('test.out', new_data, delimiter=',')
  data = numpy.genfromtxt('test.out',delimiter=",", dtype=None)
  return data


def get_column(spreadsheet, column):
  data = spreadsheet[column]
  return data.reshape(data.shape[0])

data = get_data()
#if data is homogenous, then forcibly transform into structured array
if data.dtype.names is None:
  new_dtype = list(map(lambda z:('f%d'%(z),data.dtype),range(0,data.shape[1])))
  #print('old dtype: {}, new dtype: {}'.format(data.dtype, new_dtype))
  data.dtype = new_dtype

col_name = 'f3'
print(data.dtype)
print("shape: {}, data:\n{}".format(data.shape, data))
print("shape: {}, data['{}']:\n{}".format(data[col_name].shape, col_name, data[col_name]))
print("shape: {}, data['{}']:\n{}".format(data[col_name].shape, col_name, get_column(data, col_name)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the new dtype to make `data` a structured array, the shape is changed from (10, 10) to (10, 1).  That is, it is still a two-dimensional array, with a second dimension of length 1. If the structured array had been created by `genfromtxt`, the shape would be (10,) (i.e. it would be a one-dimensional array).  You could accomplish the same by also assigning a new shape after assigning the dtype:

```
  data.shape = data.shape[0]
```

Or replace `data.dtype = new_dtype` with

```
  data = data.view(new_dtype).reshape(-1)
```

Then the structured array has shape (10,), and `data['f3']` also has shape (10,).

Note that getting a field from a structured array, say `data`, is an array *with the same shape as `data`*.  That is, `data['f3']` always has the same shape as `data`.  It is the array of the 'f3' fields of the structured array.  We often think of the fields as "columns" (especially when the structured array is 1-d), but in fact they are just names of fields within a structure.

Comment: I get that structured array is a 1-d tuple array, and that is why they have the same shape. Is there a way to properly design the `new_dtype`  to get desired shape? I think that selecting by names, or columns work kind of as a filter, I wonder if there is any copy-overhead with such access method, because it seems like `data['f3']` and `data` return different tuples. But it is just curiosity, whether  its a *copy* or a *view*. I also wonder if I should prefer one over other method that you suggested.

Comment: Not that I know of.  I would suggest trying to avoid the problem by using the `names` argument in `genfromtxt`, but if you don't know the number of columns in advance, that doesn't really help, as you've discovered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042294/genfromtxt-force-column-name-generation-for-unknown-number-of-columns

Comment: The statement `data = data.view(new_dtype).reshape(-1)` creates a new view of the underlying array of data, not a copy.  And `data['f3']` is also a view--try setting `data['f3'][0] = -1` and then inspecting `data`.

Comment: Yea well it's puzzling that it is so close to be achievable but there is a tiny bit that makes it fail in two use-cases, maybe I should ask some `numpy` officials to allow it, or tell me how to do it. Anyway thanks for the insight and answer, it works.